# Related_categories_mode="yes" outputs all channel entires and isn't related to current entry

Tags: categories, related-entries

We're build a shop and want to output similar products using categories, everything is now working apart from the related products. It's currently just outputting the latest 5 products that have been added, they don't belong to the same category at all so i'm pretty confused as to why this would happen? We have the following code:

```
{exp:channel:entries related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes" limit="5"}
{if count == 1}
<div class="related-products">
  <h2>Related products</h2>
  <ul class="product-list">
{/if}
  <li>
    <article>
      <a href="/products/{url_title}">
        <span class="product-image">
          {product_image limit="1"}
            <img src="{image:medium}" alt="{title}" height="" width="" />
          {/product_image}
        </span>
        <span class="product-text">
          <h3>{title}</h3>
            {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes" disable_javascript="yes"}
            {if on_sale}
              <div class="sale-label">Sale</div>
              {price}
              {if:else}
              {regular_price}
              {/if}
            {/exp:store:product}
        </span>
      </a>
    </article>
  </li>
  {if count == total_results}
    </ul>
  </div>
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I've tried using dynamic="no" and url_title="{segment_2}" together but this brings up the no matches, any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this `exp:channel:entries` inside another `exp:channel:entries`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all products belongs to a tax category so it was thinking everything was related, had to disable that category from the output then all was fine!

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add the `channel=""` parameter to your channel:entries tag.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, turns out I was being stupid and all products belonged to the same Tax category, hence why everything was being output, had to do category_group="not 8" and all was fine. Silly me :(!

Comment: Ah ha! Nice job tracking that down.

Comment: NOTE: I'm locking this answer because it keeps getting edited by spammers.